# Phong shading model

Tags: graphics, shader, shading

Why is the outgoing radiance equal to 0 when the angle between `n` and `l` is <= 0?

[image]

This is from the book Real-Time Rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was a very interesting question and I couldn't explain it myself. So I emailed the authors of Real-Time Rendering and one of the said that it's most likely a mistake.  It really should be `cos(theta_i) <= 0` gives `L(v) = 0`.  This means that at 90 degree angle or light projected behind the object, there is no contribution to the final value.

Comment: I actually asked veterans in GameDev the same question and they think it's a mistake as well. Funny, I kept thinking I missed something about the equation, but it really was a mistake _in the book_!